# How do I decode this string using PHP and get the value stored between the "@@@" characters?

Tags: php, string, decode

How can I decode the following String:

```
"2@@@8/11/12:09:38:41.4960@@@ W1-11004344655453108@@@100@@@84982095389@@@452040650103268@@@*654*1234567891111#@@@1@@@30"
```

and get the values between the "@@@" characters?

Comment: Have you even tried any code? If you have, please post it here. We don't code your idea, we help you with your issues...

Comment: By explode command

Answer (score 0):

As Kancho Iliev said, use PHP's [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function.

This will create an array of the substrings between the '@@@' delimiters.

For example:

```
$string        = '2@@@8/11/12:09:38:41.4960@@@ W1-11004344655453108@@@100@@@84982095389@@@452040650103268@@@*654*1234567891111#@@@1@@@30';
$substringsArr = explode('@@@', $string);
```